# If I set custom icon for navigation not catch click listener

Tags: android, navigation

I have a function where I would set custom Icon for navigation in Toolbar like this:

```
 Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        final Drawable upArrow = this.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_48dp);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("navigation", "navigastion");
            }
        });
```

And it not log, there is a method for put a custom icon on toolbar for navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `myToolbar.setNavigationIcon(...)` for catching with `setNavigationOnClickListener(...)`.

Comment: thankyou kevin, I tried but not work, but I found my error, is a conflict with drawer. Because I need have a Drawertoggle in activity, and back button in other activity